# Apply classes conditionally in ANGULAR - using controller function WITH PARAMETERS

Tags: angularjs

This is what I'm trying to do:

```
<div class="row-fluid" ng-repeat="subtopic in topic.Subtopics">
  <div class="row_divider"></div>
  <div class="row_padding">
    <span class="subtopic_level">{{subtopic.Name}}</span>
  </div>
  <div class="row-fluid" ng-repeat="subsubtopic in subtopic.Subsubtopics">
    <div class="row_divider" ng-hide="subsubtopic.Name = subtopic.Name"></div>
    <div class="row_padding" ng-hide="subsubtopic.Name = subtopic.Name">
      <span class="subsubtopic_level">{{subsubtopic.Name}}</span>
    </div>
    <div ng-class="row-fluid: true, flat: flatTopicBranch(subsubtopic.Name=subtopic.Name)" ng-repeat="lesson in subsubtopic.Lessons">
      <div class="row_divider"></div>
      <div class="row_padding">
        <span class="lesson_level">{{lesson.Name}}</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here's the function in my controller:

```
controllers.controller('YourSigmaCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
...
  $scope.flatTopicBranch = function (subsubtopic, subtopic) {
    return subsubtopic === subtopic;
  };
...
```

It's showing up in the html unchanged. Unaffected. Uneffected. Any ideas?? Is flatTopicBranch a problem because I'm deeper into the scope when I call it??

Thanks!

Comment: An advice - please provide a plunkr in the future to easily identify the cause of the issue - in your case, I make an assumption that this is what may be causing the problem. If not, then you need to provide the values associated with the code (for ex. what is present in "topic" object, what styling is associated with the classes etc.) to thoroughly understand what you are trying to achieve and what your issue is.

Comment: Your ng-hide attributes seem to have single equals signs (`=`) and I think you want double equals signs (`==`).  I'm not sure, but I would expect angular to execute that, assign `subtopic.Name` to `subsubtopic.name` and return that value.

Comment: @Jason, your comment made it painfully clear that I should just have used == and skipped the function altogether. That worked like a charm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div ng-class="row-fluid: true,
flat: flatTopicBranch(subsubtopic.Name=subtopic.Name)"
ng-repeat="lesson in subsubtopic.Lessons">
```

This is the code which contains the call to the `flatTopicBranc()` function. This function accepts two parameters. As you can see, when you are calling this function, you seem to be passing only one parameter: `flat: flatTopicBranch(subsubtopic.Name=subtopic.Name)`. Are you looking to pass two parameters?

In other words, maybe you need to change the call to `flat: flatTopicBranch(subsubtopic.Name, subtopic.Name)` - passing two parameters instead of one (you are using the equality operator, I suspect you wanted to pass two parameters separated by a comma instead of one single operator.

Comment: Damnit!!! But that's the problem. I ended up going with `ng-class="{{subsubtopic.Name==subtopic.Name}}`. I'm just an idiot.

Comment: @morgs32 wouldn't `ng-class="{{subsubtopic.Name==subtopic.Name}}` just apply a class named 'true' or a class named 'false' rather than  'flat' if i evaluates to true?